# Bases for anchoring 2" tubes?

Tags: concrete, pipe, fence, construction

Is there a base, similar to this [simpson 4" 12-gauge ez base](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Simpson-Strong-Tie-12-Gauge-Black-Powder-Coated-E-Z-Base-FPBB44/100655350), that can be used to anchor a 2" steel tube/pipe?

It would be exactly the same thing, but instead of a 4" square, it would be a 2" round tube.

Answer (score 1):

Search for "structural pipe fittings".

Here is an

[example](https://www.simplifiedbuilding.com/pipe-fittings/kee-klamp/62-standard-railing-flange).

Comment: That stuff is expensive af. Just thread the pipe and get a $2 pipe flange.

Comment: @Mazura A pipe flange for 2" pipe is not $2.  They are at least $10, perhaps that is not as much as structural pipe fittings, ( "expensive af" ) but it is not $2